# Turn off mandatory commenting on save

Tags: blueprism

I'm working on some objects in blue prism and every time I save them it requires me to add a comment or summary. This is annoying; Has anyone discovered a way to turn off mandatory commenting / summary on save in Blue Prism 6.3.0.6190?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only settings you can change is the one in 'System' section, where you can make filling the summary mandatory or optional - either you are allowed to leave it blank or you will get an error message. You cannot, however, prevent the window from appearing.

[image: Blue Prism settings]